# Hostname routing with fallback IP

Tags: macos, routing

I just set up a new FreeNAS server, with a 10Gbe network card with two ports.
One port is connected to the router for access through the network, the other is connected *via* a 10Gbe ethernet adapter to my Macbook Pro for fast access.

The idea is the following: when I need speed, I can directly connect to the FreeNAS with the adapter. Otherwise, I can still have *slow* access through the local network (WiFi).

If I only connected manually, I could manually connect to the NAS using the right IP address depending on the interface I use. However with TimeMachine, things get a bit messier.
I tried to workaround the 2 IPs issue using the hostname `truenas` and the domain `local` of my NAS. It works fine if one interface is connected at a time, but in case the two are connected, it resolves alternatively to the 2 IPs, I can check it using `route get truenas.local`. In this case, TimeMachine fails as the connection is dropped.

My question is therefore:
is there a way to resolve a hostname, let's say `clevertruenas`, that would always preferentially resolves to the direct attached IP address of my server, and if not available, to the local network IP address of my server.

Thanks for your help and suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in the "host file" ([sudo vim /etc/hosts](https://www.alphr.com/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/)). There you can set a domain name to a specific IP address.

As an example the following entry redirects `www.facebook.com` to `170.149.172.130`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This allows to set a domain name to _ONE_  specific IP, but it doesn't fallback to another one in case the IP is not available.
Taking your example redirecting `www.facebook.com` to `170.149.172.130`, could it fallback to `170.149.172.131` in case `170.149.172.130` times out ?

Comment: It works on a DNS server (round robin), but I don't know if you can set in in the host file. In this case you might install a simple DNS server locally on your laptop and add both IPs to the DNS name.

Comment: quick check: [no it doesn't](https://serverfault.com/questions/429839/assign-multiple-ips-to-1-entry-in-hosts-file) (the link gives you a few suggestion for the setup you need)